# What algorithm can be used to reconstruct a self similar time series from a portion of it?

Tags: fractals

I am working on a process which produces time series similar to the one shown in the graph below:

[image]

I calculated Fractal dimension $D$ and Generalised Hurst Exponent $H$, to confirm that equality $D=n+1-H$ holds for $n=1$.

I followed the line of reasoning in [this paper](https://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2003/tr425.pdf), to conclude that this is indeed a self similar signal (with an $H \approx 0.8$ and $D \approx 1.2$).

Now, assuming that I have access to only a final portion of the signal, bounded in red box on the graph, the question is: How I can reconstruct the signal from $t=0$ to the beginning  of the red box?